# Implementing an NMS

Tags: monitoring, patch-management

We are looking to implement an NMS (netork monitoring software) in our company and have found many different products; Nagios, Kaseya, Zabbix, Zenoss, Munin, OpenNMS.

The core functionality that we need is patch management and server monitoring if a server goes down. We would use the NMS to monitor new OS servers that come out, and patch them; so it must provide compatibility for new server OS's almost immediately. Which of the products listed would do this?

Not to be biased but we would like to support FOSS if it all possible.

Comment: Almost no network monitoring systems does patch management.  Network monitoring is difficult enough to do by itself.

Comment: Kaseya, if I remember correctly, is not a true network monitoring application. I believe its a managed services platform that will allow you to add in network monitoring as part of your package.

Answer (score 1):

As @Zoredache pointed out monitoring systems don't usually do patch management.  Both are pretty complex tasks to perform and you'll want two separate software packages to perform these tasks.